# Remove .PHP and redirect through htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is that possible to hide the .PHP extension and redirect the URL at same time.

example : http://example.com/test need to redirect to http://someothersite.com

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/test http://someothersite.com
```

But its not working.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test http://someothersite.com [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

The code above is not tested, but it should give you an idea about it. Use [`L` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) after each set of rules, as it stops processing of the rest of the rules.

Answer (score 1):

You need just this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [R=301,L]
```

For cross domain rewriting:

```
RewriteRule ^test http://someothersite.com [R=301,L]
```

Allways use L = 301 for permanent redirectings.